# Joins Specific Querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and I have a question on how to return specific values (I'm not sure 100% if I should be using joins or subqueries.) I tried to put an example below of what I'm trying to do and hopefully someone can help me out with this.

I have two tables below:

Table 1

| Record | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | History |
| 101 | Science |
| 102 | Art |
| 103 | Music |

Table 2

| Record | Course |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Intro |
| 100 | Intermediate |
| 101 | Intermediate |
| 101 | Advanced |
| 102 | Intro |
| 102 | Intermediate |
| 103 | Intermediate |
| 103 | Advanced |

I want to join the two tables together, but only bring back the columns 'Record' and 'Topic' ONLY where the Record DOES NOT have an 'Intro' course attached to it.

So I would want to bring back the following results (since both Courses do not have an Intro class):

| Record | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Science |
| 103 | Music |

So far I've had no luck and am bringing back more records than I should so any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT Record, Topic
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHRE t2.Record = t1.Record AND
         t2.Course = 'Intro'
);
```